# Pandas ffill based on condition

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame of empty daily prices. I have then written a function which give week commencing monday dates.

```
  Day   WC Monday   Price 1  Price 2
1/1/12  1/1/12      44        34
2/1/13  1/1/12      55        34
3/1/12  1/1/12      44        34
4/1/13  1/1/12      NA        NA
5/1/12  1/1/12      NA        NA
6/1/13  1/1/12      34        NA
7/1/12  1/1/12      33        NA
8/1/13  8/1/12      12        NA
9/1/12  8/1/12      34        NA
10/1/13 8/1/12      23        NA
```

I want to say if the price only has NAs left until the end of the column, then fill with the last value only to the end of the incomplete week

So the expected output is:

```
  Day   WC Monday   Price 1  Price 2
1/1/12  1/1/12      44        34
2/1/13  1/1/12      55        34
3/1/12  1/1/12      44        34
4/1/13  1/1/12      NA        34
5/1/12  1/1/12      NA        34
6/1/13  1/1/12      34        34
7/1/12  1/1/12      33        34
8/1/13  8/1/12      12        NA
9/1/12  8/1/12      34        NA
10/1/13 8/1/12      23        NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is test, if last row per group is missing values by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and then replace missing values with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
c = ['Price 1','Price 2']
m = df.isna().groupby('WC Monday')[c].transform('last')

df[c] = df[c].mask(m, df.groupby('WC Monday')[c].ffill())
print (df)
       Day WC Monday  Price 1  Price 2
0   1/1/12    1/1/12     44.0     34.0
1   2/1/13    1/1/12     55.0     34.0
2   3/1/12    1/1/12     44.0     34.0
3   4/1/13    1/1/12      NaN     34.0
4   5/1/12    1/1/12      NaN     34.0
5   6/1/13    1/1/12     34.0     34.0
6   7/1/12    1/1/12     33.0     34.0
7   8/1/13    8/1/12     12.0      NaN
8   9/1/12    8/1/12     34.0      NaN
9  10/1/13    8/1/12     23.0      NaN
```

Comment: This is great. thanks. Is there a tidy way of saying, do the same for values going up the dataframe. So if its all NAs at the start, fill upwards only to complete the full week. (sorry for not putting that in the original questions)

Comment: @fred.schwartz - Do you think same solution only change `last` to `first` and `ffill` to `bfill` ?